# Why does the Heroku Rails App crash after upgrading Rails to 6.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an application that I successfully uploaded to Heroku and everything worked fine. After updating with the `rails app:update` command from version 6.0.0rc1 to 6.0.0, I deployed the application to heroku and after that the Heroku is crashed when the server launch.

```
2019-08-20T12:45:56.047319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-08-20T12:46:01.995009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2019-08-20T12:46:04.051365+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-08-20T12:46:04.051387+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-08-20T12:46:04.051389+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-08-20T12:46:04.051390+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-08-20T12:46:08.886669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-08-20T12:46:08.769945+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:32178
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770225+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770272+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770276+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `initialize'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770277+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `open'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770278+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:133:in `write_pid'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770280+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:106:in `write_state'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770281+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770282+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:186:in `run'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770284+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770285+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770287+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.770289+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2019-08-20T12:46:08.867275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

For some reason, the `tmp/pids/server.pid` is not created when the server starts.

Can you please help me with a solution to this problem?
I did not find a solution in google

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by removing the line `pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }` from the `config/puma.rb` that was added during the rails upgrade :)

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting, but thanks for coming back and answering

Comment: Probably, You have merged instead of inspecting file changes on upgrade!

Comment: Yes, but I inspected only those files that I changed before upgrading.

Comment: I had the same problem when upgrading from Rails 4.2.11.1 to Rails 5.2.5.  Removing that line also fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 16):

You'll need to modify your `.gitignore` file to explicitly let through the `tmp/pids` directory with a `.keep` file. Ensure your `.gitignore` looks like this:

```
/tmp/*
/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/.keep
!/tmp/pids
!/tmp/pids/.keep
```

And then `touch tmp/pids/.keep`.

Comment: didn't work... pids folder is not pushed to heroku got error-> launcher.rb:244:in `write': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: This happened to me when I upgrade to 5.2.6 however there was `Ignore pidfiles, but keep the directory.` part in `.gitignore` file when `rails new`.

Comment: This worked for me on Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `tmp/pids` folder to version control using a `.keep` file. This puts the folder in version control, so when it gets cloned to Heroku, the folder is there.

You will also probably have to edit your .gitignore file so it doesn't ignore the `tmp/pids` directory.